# Li product cards with Radio buttons conflict - React

Tags: reactjs

I am rendering product cards with radio buttons on each card. Radio buttons have some logic to show price option based on the selected one. Having an issue when rendering a few cards and selecting option it automatically populate selection on all cards.

Here is my component code:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import styles from "./PizzaListItem.module.css";

import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class PizzaListItem extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      size: "M",
    };
    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
  }

  handleChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      size: event.target.value,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
   <>

          {this.props.products.map((product) => (
            <li key={product._id} className={styles.pizzaListCard}>
              <div>
                <img
                  src={product.images[0]}
                  width="280"
                  height="192"
                  className={styles.imageItem}
                />
              </div>
              <div className={styles.descriptionContainer}>
                <p className={styles.heading}>{product.name}</p>
                <ul className={styles.ingredients}>
                  {product.ingredients.map((ingredient) => (
                    <li key={ingredient._id}>
                      <span className={styles.ingredientItem}>
                        {ingredient.name}
                      </span>
                    </li>
                  ))}
                </ul>
                <form>
                  <ul className={styles.radioButtonsList}>
                    <li>
                      <label className={styles.sizeLabel}>
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          value="M"
                          checked={this.state.size === "M"}
                          onChange={this.handleChange}
                          className={styles.radioButton}
                        />
                        <span className={styles.sizeText}>M</span>
                      </label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                      <label className={styles.sizeLabelL}>
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          value="L"
                          checked={this.state.size === "L"}
                          onChange={this.handleChange}
                          className={styles.radioButton}
                        />
                        <span className={styles.sizeTextL}>L</span>
                      </label>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                      <label className={styles.sizeLabelXL}>
                        <input
                          type="radio"
                          value="XL"
                          checked={this.state.size === "XL"}
                          onChange={this.handleChange}
                          className={styles.radioButton}
                        />
                        <span className={styles.sizeText}>XL</span>
                      </label>
                    </li>
                  </ul>

                  <span className={styles.price}>
                    {product.price[this.state.size]}.00
                  </span>
                  <span className={styles.currency}> {product.currency}</span>

                  <button
                    className={styles.addCart}
                    type="submit"
                    onClick={() => {}}
                  >
                    В корзину
                  </button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </li>
          ))}
       </>

    );
  }
}
```

I kinda understand what is the problem. is that all cards looking at state and getting updated once state changes. Just stuck on how to solve it.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: here is the screenshoot of the page: https://prnt.sc/sy70sa

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you use the same state for every card.
You probably want to keep a local state for each card

Here's a solution:

```js
// A single pizza card
// Usage:
// <ul>{products.map(product => <PizzaListItem {...product} />)}</ul>
// 

function PizzaListItem(props) {
  const [selectedSize, setSelectedSize] = useState('M')

  function handleChange(event) {
    setSelectedSize(event.target.value)
  }

  return (
    <li key={props._id} className={styles.pizzaListCard}>
      <div>
        <img
          src={props.images[0]}
          width="280"
          height="192"
          className={styles.imageItem}
        />
      </div>
      <div className={styles.descriptionContainer}>
        <p className={styles.heading}>{props.name}</p>
        <ul className={styles.ingredients}>
          {props.ingredients.map((ingredient) => (
            <li key={ingredient._id}>
              <span className={styles.ingredientItem}>{ingredient.name}</span>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
        <form>
          <ul className={styles.radioButtonsList}>
            {['M', 'L', 'XL'].map((size) => (
              <li>
                <label className={styles.sizeLabel}>
                  <input
                    type="radio"
                    value="M"
                    checked={size === selectedSize}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    className={styles.radioButton}
                  />
                  <span className={styles.sizeText}>{size}</span>
                </label>
              </li>
            ))}
          </ul>

          <span className={styles.price}>{props.price[selectedSize]}.00</span>
          <span className={styles.currency}> {props.currency}</span>

          <button className={styles.addCart} type="submit" onClick={() => {}}>
            В корзину
          </button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </li>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alessandro, tried to apply your code. it doesnt work. Radio buttons are not active, you cannot pick your choice https://prnt.sc/sy7nar

Comment: I found an issue: it was in "value" attribute. Changed it to {size} and it works fine. Thank you!